# How to accept values as doubles in a textbox in ASPX C# Website?

Tags: c#, double, decimal

The following code allows to enter only integers, but instead of only integers, I need to give the option to the user to enter double (0.00). Any suggestions or modification?

```
if (_txStaticPressureUpdate.Trim() == "")
    {

        txSystemMessage.Text = "Field 'Static Pressure' is empty. Please enter a valid value.";
        txSystemMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }

    //check that record info entered consists of numbers only / no special characters or letters
    for (int j = 0; j < _txStaticPressureUpdate.Length; j++)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(_txStaticPressureUpdate[j]))
        {
            txSystemMessage.Text = "Field 'Static Pressure' has an invalid value.";
            txSystemMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            staticPressure = double.Parse(txStaticPressureUpdate.Text.Trim());
        }
    }
```

I am working on an ASPX/C# website. Many of the options available are for WinForms. It sitll works, but to be more precise in the final result of the formula, I look to use doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

double.TryParse could be used to check the entered string is a double. It returns a bool indicating if the parse succeeded, and passes out the parsed value to a variable.

Eg.

```
    if (!double.TryParse(_txStaticPressureUpdate.Text.Trim(), out staticPressure))
    {
        txSystemMessage.Text = "Field 'Static Pressure' has an invalid value.";
        txSystemMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }
```

You won't need to loop through and check the individual characters either.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much, @James
Awesome! That certainly worked perfectly!